# Why aren't my custom post fields aren't showing up in the view?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom post as below.  It displays fine in my backend admin panel, but when I go to view the post, it's empty.  See [here](http://nicolaelvin.com/community/give/413/) for one of my custom posts.  Have I missed something out that tells wordpresshwo to display the fields?

```
add_action('init', 'give_gnt_register');

function give_gnt_register() {

$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Offered items'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Item'),
    'add_new' => _x('Give an item away'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Give a new item away'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit item'),
    'new_item' => __('Give Item Away'),
    'view_item' => __('View Item'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Offered Items'),
    'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/article16.png',
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'taxonomies' => array('category'),
    'supports' => array('title','thumbnail', 'custom-fields','comments')
  ); 

register_post_type( 'give' , $args );
```

}

Comment: I wonder if it is because my custom post type uses the plugin advanced custom fields to display the fields I want

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('init', 'give_gnt_register');
function give_gnt_register() {
wp_create_category('Give');
$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Offered items'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Item'),
    'add_new' => _x('Give an item away'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Give a new item away'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit item'),
    'new_item' => __('Give Item Away'),
    'view_item' => __('View Item'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Offered Items'),
    'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/article16.png',
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'taxonomies' => array('category'),
    'supports' => array('title','thumbnail', 'custom-fields','comments')
  ); 

    // create "give" post type
    register_post_type('give', $args);
}
```

i just add the `wp_create_category`.

good luck.